Find the value of a for which the sum of the elements of the set $A(a) ∩ N$ is 203
The problem
Let a be a natural number and $A(a) = \{\sqrt{a^2+1}, \sqrt{a^2+2},... , \sqrt{a^2+29a+201} \}$. The value of
a for which the sum of the elements of the set $A(a) ∩ N$ is $203$ is...
my idea
We actually need to find the number $a$ for which $A= \{a^2+1, a^2+2, ... a^2+29a+201\}$ has $203$ square numbers
I did some code in C++ and found out the answer is $7$ this might help somehow.
I don't know what to do from here. Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

$a^2+1, a^2+2 $ are never squares

@RossMillikan You are sure??? I manually checked it and its correct. We want the sum of the elements to be 203, NOT THE CARDINAL...

@trula I agree, but how is going to help...

What is the largest square number below $a^2+29a+201?$

Corrected thanks to comment by Empy2
The numbers that yield integer square roots will be of the forms $(a+1)^2,(a+2)^2,\dots,(a+k)^2$ and their square roots will be $a+1,a+2,\dots a+k$. Their sum will be either $ka+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=k(a+\frac{k+1}{2})$, or alternatively $\frac{k}{2}(2a+k+1)$.
Since the sum equals $203$ we observe that $k$ or $\frac{k}{2}$ must be a factor of $203=7\cdot29$
$k=29$ or $k=58$ are plainly too large, so the only possibilities left are $k=7$ or $k=14$.
Choosing $k=7$, we obtain $7a+28=203 \Rightarrow a=25$. This would afford the collection $26,27,28,29,30,31,32$ which sums to $203$. However, $a=25 \Rightarrow a^2+29a+201=1601$ which allows for integer members of $A(a)$ to include the additional values of $33,\dots,40$. So $k=7$ is not correct.
Choosing $k=14$, we obtain $14a+105=203 \Rightarrow a=7$. This would afford the collection $8,9,10,\dots,20,21$ which sums to $203$. $a=7 \Rightarrow a^2+29a+201=453$. In this case, $21^2=441<453<484=22^2$ so there are no larger integer members of $A(a)$
This establishes $a=7$ as the correct answer, as found by OP by computer calculation.

With the half factor, you might have $14$

The last term is $a^2+29a+201=(a+14)^2+a+5\lt (a+15)^2$ so there are $14$ terms to be consider. It follows the equation
$$(a+1)+(a+2)+\cdots+(a+14)=14a+\dfrac{14\times15}{2}=203\Rightarrow 14a=98$$ then the value $\boxed{a=7}$
